# texts and want to tap on texts to go to another view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, text

I am trying to make an app that will have a view full of texts and when the user click on a sentence it would take him to another view. However, it depends on what sentence the user clicks on, that the app takes the user to which view. So, different sentences and different views. If the user presses on senetence1, the app would take him to viewController1. If the user presses sentence2, the app would take him to viewController2, and so no. Is it possible to make this app using an image?. Supposes that I have an image and it is filled with texts, can I control every sentence written on the image?. Also, please explain what way is better, texts or an image, and how can I apply this idea?.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would possibly be a UITextView or TTTAttributedLabel with attributed strings with links attached to them and styled appropriately.